# jquery validation range not working with negative number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation to ensure my users do not enter a negative value into a text field.

I have everything set up correctly and the validation is working for certain things, just not the a range. if I input a negative value, validation still passes.
Has anyone encountered this?

```
 <input data-affects="Coaches" data-old="40" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Maximum Students must be a number." data-val-range="The field Maximum Students must be between 0 and 200." data-val-range-max="200" data-val-range-min="0" id="NumStudentsMax" name="NumStudentsMax" type="number" value="40" aria-invalid="false" class="valid"/>


var foo = null;
$("input").blur(function(e){
    foo = $("form").validate($(this));
    alert(foo.errorList.length > 0);
});
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/guzzjty1/5/

Comment: Also try using [the latest version of the plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js) rather than one that is five-years-old.

Comment: It's not working at all in Safari for me.  All numbers positive and negative will pass validation as if `data-val-range-max` and `data-val-range-min` are totally ignored.

Comment: @Sparky, thats the problem. Annoying

Comment: But that's not the same problem you described in the OP.  You said validation passes negative numbers, but forgot to mention that validation also passes any number outside the specified range.

Answer (score 1):

add `min="0"` to your input :-

```
  <input data-affects="Coaches" data-old="40" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Maximum Students must be a number." data-val-range="The field Maximum Students must be between 0 and 200." data-val-range-max="200" data-val-range-min="0" id="NumStudentsMax" name="NumStudentsMax" min="0" type="number" value="40" aria-invalid="false" class="valid"/>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzzjty1/6/)

Comment: your demo returned true? but i thought there is no need for min, as the data-val-range-min is what validation looks at

Comment: @LiamHT he don't need `data-val-range-min ` just `min` will work fine

Comment: data-val-range-min is what is returned by the ASP.NET MVC framework though.

Comment: @LiamHT may be but i don't know much about that but in simple html it worked with min attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is due to html validation and unobtrusive validation becoming more inline. as mentioned by Mohit, it now works with the 'min' attribute.

As asp.net mvc adds the data-val-range-min value. my quick fix just took that value and inserted a 'min' attribute with the same value, using javascript

```
   //fix validator for range
    $("[data-val-range-min]").each(function (e) {
      var t =  $("[data-val-range-min]:eq("+e+")")
    t.attr("min", t.attr("data-val-range-min"));
    });
    $("[data-val-range-max]").each(function (e) {
        var t = $("[data-val-range-max]:eq(" + e + ")")
        t.attr("max", t.attr("data-val-range-max"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `data-val-range-min="5E-324"` as an attribute to your input
This says values greater than 0. Actually 5E-324 is the smallest positive value.